# Codeigniter Search Query with 2 words

Tags: php, database, codeigniter

I have a property site built on codeIgniter which searches using a form. Everything is working fine unless you search with 2 words and it then brings up no results even thought the keywords are there. I cannot see where I have gone wrong. The URL looks fine and it puts the keywording in there like

eg:

```
    /family%20home/
```

but brings no results back. If you just search family the results come back fine.

Hope someone can help with this! :-)

The controller looks like:

```
function index($page=0,$keyword='0',$min='0',$max='0',$bed='0',$rentbuy='0',$ord_by='DESC')
{ 
  $condition=" where 1 ";
  $keyword=empty($keyword)?(!empty($_POST["keyword"])?trim($_POST["keyword"]):'0'):$keyword;
  if(!empty($keyword)){
    $data['keyword']=$keyword;
    $condition.=" and (town like '%$keyword%' or street like '%$keyword%' or postcode like '%$keyword%' or main_advert like '%$keyword%' or main_advert2 like '%$keyword%' or main_advert3 like '%$keyword%' or main_advert4 like '%$keyword%')";
  }
  $bed=empty($bed)?(!empty($_POST["bed"])?$_POST["bed"]:'0'):$bed;
  if($bed>0){
    $condition.=" and bedrooms>=$bed";
  }    
  $min=empty($min)?(!empty($_POST["min"])?$_POST["min"]:0):$min;
  if($min>0){
    $condition.=" and price>=$min";
  }       
  $max=empty($max)?(!empty($_POST["max"])?$_POST["max"]:0):$max;
  if($max>0){
    $condition.=" and price<=$max";
  }       
 $orderby=' order by price DESC';
 // $ord_by=(!empty($_POST["ord_by"]))?$_POST["ord_by"]:$ord_by;      
  $rentbuy=empty($rentbuy)?(!empty($_POST["rentbuy"])?$_POST["rentbuy"]:'0'):$rentbuy;
  if(!empty($rentbuy)){
  $rarry=array('','Residential Sales','Residential Lettings');
    $condition.=" and department='".$rarry[$rentbuy]."'";
  }
  //echo $condition;
  $perpage=4;
  $start=($page);

  $limit=" LIMIT ".$start.",".$perpage."";

    $data["count"] = $this->property->get_count($condition);
    $data["list"] = $this->property->get_list($condition.$orderby.$limit);
    $config['urlpara']='/'.$keyword."/".$min."/".$max."/".$bed."/".$rentbuy."/".$ord_by."/";
    $config['total_rows']=$data["count"] ;
    $config['uri_segment']=3;
    $config['per_page']=$perpage;
    $config['base_url']=base_url().'/properties/index/';

    $this->load->library('pagination');
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);

    $data['links']=$this->pagination->create_links();
    if($_POST){
        redirect(base_url().'properties/index/0'.$config['urlpara']);       
    }
    $data['page']=$page;
    $data['bed']=$bed;
    $data['min']=$min;
    $data['max']=$max;
    $data['rentbuy']=$rentbuy;
    $data['ord_by']=$ord_by;       
    $this->_common($data);
    $this->load->view('property_results',$data);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if keyword is "Family%20home" have you tried urldecode() to remove the url encoding?

Comment: Yes, this still brings back 0 results when using urldecode. I feel sure it is something in the controller that is not passing over the keywords correctly.

Answer (score 1):

In codeigniter when query string or key words are sent to a controller like

```
$query="World Hospital";
echo site_url('Controller/Controller_Function/'.$query);
```

Codeigniter assumes the $query as URL and encodes it which becomes World%20Hospital. Ofcourse mysql will not give you result with this string. What you need is to decode the string before actually using the variable in your controller as JCO mentioned in above answer. Do it as;

```
Public function something()
{
   $my_query=urldecode($this->url->segment(3));
   // Now you can use $my_query in your query.
}
```

Hope this will work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure i understand what you actually need to do.
If you want to perform a search using multiple keywords, you would then could explode the keywords variable into an array

```
$keywords=explode(' ',$keywords);
```

and then make a loop and build your search query